# ng-options with array of objects in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, drop-down-menu, javascript-objects, ng-options

I see a number of references to variations of what I'm seeing all over the net but can't seem to find an actual solution.  I'm trying to get an existing set of data to populate a select list using AngularJs. I can get it to work but with problematic results.

My dataset is an array that is populated earlier for a different directive that consists of a list of javascript object instances. (I created to objects to represent Doctrine entities and populate them from json data)

```
var ListtypeModel = function(data) {
    var dataIsObj = (typeof(data) == "object");
    this.ListtypeId   = (dataIsObj && (data.ListtypeId > 0))                   ? data.ListtypeId   : null;
    this.ListtypeName = (dataIsObj && (typeof(data.ListtypeName) == "string")) ? data.ListtypeName : null;

    // alias functions
    this.getId   = function() { return this.ListtypeId; }
    this.getName = function() { return this.ListtypeName; }
};

function groupTypes(inData) {
    var grouped = [];
    for(var type in inData) {
        var gType = new ListtypeModel(inData[type]);
        grouped.push(gType);
    }
    return grouped;
}
```

I retrieve the info when drawing the upper part of a tree menu in the main controller:

```
// run at startup
$http.get("<?= $this->basePath(); ?>/json/listtypes")
.success(
    function (response) {
        $scope.types = groupTypes(response.types); // groupLists(response);
    }
);
```

Since I want to re-use this for the select menu, I pass the 'types' variable down the tree through the scope until it gets to the pop-up edit directive.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="listedit.html">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width:300px;" ng-show="showlistedit">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-show="(currentlist.ListId > 0)">
            Id: {{ currentlist.ListId  }}
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="listform.listid " ngDisabled="!(currentlist.ListId  > 0)" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <label for="ListName">Name</label>
            <input name="ListName"  type="text" ng-model="listform.name" />
            <br />
            <label for="ListtypeId">Type {{types}}</label>
            <select ng-model="listform.typeid">
                <option ng-selected="listtype.getId() == listform.typeid" ng-repeat="listtype in types" value="{{listtype.getId()}}">{{listtype.getName()}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <span ng-click="saveList()">[save]</span>
    </div>
</script>

    .directive(
        'listedit',
        function($http) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    currenttype: '=',
                    currentlist: '=',
                    showlistedit: '=',
                    types: '='
                },
                templateUrl: 'listedit.html',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.listform = {
                        listid : scope.currentlist.ListId,
                        name   : scope.currentlist.ListName,
                        typeid : scope.currentlist.ListtypeId
                    };
                    scope.saveList = function () {
                        alert('in saveList');
                        var postData = $.param({
                            ListId       : scope.listform.listid,
                            ListName     : scope.listform.name,
                            ListtypeId   : scope.listform.typeid
                        });
                        $http({
                            url: '<?= $this->basePath(); ?>/json/lists/save',
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: postData,
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                        })
                            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                alert('saveList success');
                            })
                            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                alert('saveList failure');
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

I have also tried removing the  tag and using `ng-options="listtype.ListtypeId as listtype.ListtypeName for listtype in types"` within the select tag.

Whenever I use the option tag with the ng-repeat, I get two blanks at the top of the select list:

```
<option value="? number:1 ?"></option>
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
```

Whenever I use the ng-options, the list shows up twice with duplicates of the items in the array.  I saw at least one post on the duplicates for the ng-options saying that running a $compile would cause it to compile twice, but I have no compile in that directive.

I just need to know how to get angularjs to build the select list without duplicates and without blanks.

Here are the variables as seen in console.log() output in chrome:

```
types as seen in javascript console:
[ListtypeModel, ListtypeModel, ListtypeModel]
  0: ListtypeModel
    $$hashKey: "object:3"
    ListtypeId: 1
    ListtypeName: "Materials"
    getId: function () { return this.ListtypeId; }
    getName: function () { return this.ListtypeName; }
    __proto__: ListtypeModel
  1: ListtypeModel
    $$hashKey: "object:4"
    ListtypeId: 2
    ListtypeName: "Material Collection List"
    getId: function () { return this.ListtypeId; }
    getName: function () { return this.ListtypeName; }
    __proto__: ListtypeModel
  2: ListtypeModel
    $$hashKey: "object:5"
    ListtypeId: 3
    ListtypeName: "Material Collection"
    getId: function () { return this.ListtypeId; }
    getName: function () { return this.ListtypeName; }
    __proto__: ListtypeModel
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array[0]


listform as seen in console.log
  Object {listid: 1, name: "All Materials", typeid: 1}
```

Comment: I should also add the ng-options stays with 2 sets of duplicate options, both properly pre-select the prior value, but once I change the value in the ng-repeat option version, the two blanks disapeer.

Answer (score 0):

After considerable tinkering, i started to become suspicious that it might have something to do with the way the directive elements were nested in the tree structure. One of the things I was playing with was accessing the templateCache directly to pull up content and append it only when a tree would have content under it's current branch.

i.e. a listType branches down to lists that match that type. A List then has an array of listItems. listItems can have listItemoptions. If for any reason a type didn't match any currently define lists, a list didn't yet have any items in it or an item had no options associated with it, I didn't see any reason to even include the code to allow you to expand those branches further, so I used a conditional in the link followed by a compile call.

e.g.

```
if (angular.isArray(scope.currentitem.Itemoptions)) {
    element.append($templateCache.get('itemfunc.html'));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope)
}
```

I'm not sure if it was the compiles nested further down the tree or the fact I was dropping in an item out of the template cache, but when I included the content directly in the layer, the strange behaviors went away.

So I guess I'll just hide them with an ng-show condition instead.